# Eloquent model relationship for final table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've the following tables

```
Cities (City model)


+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | tokyo |
+----+-------+


events (Event model)

+----+--------------------+---------+
| id |       title        | city_id |
+----+--------------------+---------+
|  1 | Biggest event ever |       1 |
+----+--------------------+---------+


event_user_applications (EventUserApplication model)


+----+----------+---------+
| id | event_id | user_id |
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 |        1 |       1 |
+----+----------+---------+
```

How do I get the `city` on `EventUserApplication` model.
I tried both of this in the `EventUserApplication`

```
    public function city()
    {
//        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\City', 'city_id')->using('App\Model\Event', 'event_id');
//        return $this->hasOneThrough('App\Model\City', 'App\Model\Event', 'city_id', 'id');
    }
```

Can't get any of this to work. Already spent hours. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: City to Events :    hasMany

Event to City  :    belongsTo

Event to Users :    belongsToMany

User to Events :    belongsToMany

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with the help of my friend. This is what I did to get the city.

```
$applications = EventUserApplication::with(
        'user:id,name,phone,email,date_of_birth',
        'event:id,title,area_id,area_city_id',
        'event.city' // nester eager loading
    )->latest()->get();
```

In the `Event` model, I already had this

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\City', 'area_city_id');
}
```

It's the `Nester Eager Loading` which was needed.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can use hasOnThrough relationship EventUserApplication has One city Through Event.

Edit:The 5th parameter should be event_id and there should be another parameter which is id (foreign key of  event table)

Comment: return $this->hasOneThrough('App\Model\City', 'App\Model\Event', 'area_city_id', 'id');